# I do not charge the PDO data query and not show data(show blank)

Tags: mysql, pdo

I need some help with the following code. It does not show any error messages or the PDO query data. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    include_once('../conexion.php');
    $equipoida = $_POST['equipoida'];
    $desde = $_POST['desde'];
    $hasta = $_POST['hasta'];        
    $fechas = "SELECT horatrabajo.idequipo, CONCAT(equipo.nombre,' ',equipo.modelo,' ',equipo.marca) AS flota, horatrabajo.horastrab, horatrabajo.fecha FROM horatrabajo INNER JOIN equipo ON horatrabajo.idequipo = equipo.idequipo WHERE horatrabajo.idequipo = $equipoida AND fecha BETWEEN $desde AND $hasta ORDER BY fecha ASC";
    $stmtfechas = $DB_con->query($fechas);
    $filasfechas =$stmtfechas->fetchAll();
    if (empty($filasfechas)) 
        {
            $resultado = "No hay Fechas Disponibles!";
        }
    foreach ($filasfechas as $filaflo)
        {
            print $filaflo['idequipo'].' '.$filaflo['horastrab'].' '.$filaflo['fecha'];
        }
```

Comment: Please provide more information or execute $fechas directly in your database..

Comment: Hello friend when I print $fechas show this: SELECT horatrabajo.idequipo, CONCAT(equipo.nombre,' ',equipo.modelo,' ',equipo.marca) AS flota, horatrabajo.horastrab, horatrabajo.fecha FROM horatrabajo INNER JOIN equipo ON horatrabajo.idequipo = equipo.idequipo WHERE horatrabajo.idequipo = 1 AND fecha BETWEEN 2016-01-01 AND 2016-01-03 ORDER BY fecha ASC

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL); and try to execute this query in mysql to check whether data exists or not.